# Subquery returned more than 1 value. Cannot resolve

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm asking this problem for the second time, but can't find the answer please help.
I want to update on my 'MakinelerVeParcalar' table with this query ;

```
UPDATE MakinelerVeParcalar SET Durum = 'Montaj' WHERE ID = 161
```

And I got this error;

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure trgSureUpdate, Line 31 [Batch Start Line 0] Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

My trgSureUpdate(Trigger)

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trgSureUpdate]
            ON [dbo].[MakinelerVeParcalar]
            AFTER UPDATE
            AS 
            BEGIN

                DECLARE @count INT
                DECLARE @idinserted INT
                DECLARE @duruminserted VARCHAR(50)
                DECLARE @max INT
                DECLARE @iddeleted INT
                DECLARE @durumdeleted VARCHAR(50)
                DECLARE @datediff INT
                DECLARE @durumbilgisi varchar(50)
                DECLARE @sureinserted INT
                DECLARE @suredeleted INT
                DECLARE @diffdate INT

                SELECT @idinserted = ID from inserted  <-- Line 31
                SELECT @duruminserted = Durum from inserted
                SELECT @iddeleted = ID from deleted
                SELECT @durumdeleted = Durum from deleted

                SET @count = (SELECT count(*) FROM Sure WHERE ID = @idinserted and Asama = @duruminserted)
                SET @max = (SELECT max(SiraNo) FROM Sure WHERE ID = @idinserted)
                SET @durumbilgisi = (SELECT DurumBilgisi FROM DurumBilgisi WHERE ID = @idinserted)
                SET @sureinserted = (SELECT Sure FROM Sure WHERE ID = @idinserted and Asama = @duruminserted)
                SET @suredeleted = (SELECT Sure FROM Sure WHERE ID = @iddeleted and Asama = @durumdeleted)

                IF @duruminserted != @durumdeleted
                BEGIN


                    IF @durumbilgisi != 'Bitti'
                    BEGIN
                        UPDATE Sure Set Cikis = GETDATE() WHERE Asama = @durumdeleted and ID = @idinserted and SiraNo = @max
                        SET @diffdate = DATEDIFF (SECOND,(SELECT Giris FROM Sure WHERE ID = @idinserted and SiraNo = @max),(SELECT Cikis FROM Sure WHERE ID = @idinserted and SiraNo = @max))
                        UPDATE Sure SET Sure = (@diffdate) WHERE ID = @idinserted and SiraNo = @max
                    END
                    INSERT INTO Sure (ID,Asama,Giris,Cikis,Sure,SiraNo) VALUES(@idinserted,@duruminserted,GETDATE(),NULL,0,(@max+1))
                    UPDATE DurumBilgisi SET DurumBilgisi = 'Devam Ediyor' WHERE ID = @idinserted
                END
            END
```

If you need tables I can send all the tables. Thanks...

Comment: Your trigger code is just totally bogus.  You have ignored that `inserted` and `deleted` can have more than one row.  I would suggest deleting this question and asking another question.  Include sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to accomplish.

Comment: OK. Thank you for your comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to limit the rows in `subquery` by using `top` clause :

```
 SELECT TOP (1) @durumbilgisi = DurumBilgisi 
 FROM DurumBilgisi 
 WHERE ID = @idinserted
 ORDER BY ??

 SELECT TOP (1) @sureinserted = Sure 
 FROM Sure 
 WHERE ID = @idinserted and Asama = @duruminserted
 ORDER BY ??

 SELECT TOP (1) @suredeleted = Sure 
 FROM Sure 
 WHERE ID = @iddeleted and Asama = @durumdeleted
 ORDER BY ??
```

`??` ordering column that specify your column ordering.

Comment: *This is just a workaround!* @HasanKaanTURAN I think need to have a look at data and check why it returning two or more rows if you are *expecting`* one to be a return and if you are taking one row then on which basis it will return the first one?

Comment: This is a really bad solution.  Although it fixes the proximal cause of the error, it does not fix the code.  The code is totally buggy if more than one row is being updated.  That is the problem that should be addressed.

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices.

First:- if returns same records value then write down.

```
 SET @durumbilgisi = (SELECT DISTINCT DurumBilgisi FROM DurumBilgisi WHERE ID = @idinserted)
 SET @sureinserted = (SELECT DISTINCT  Sure FROM Sure WHERE ID = @idinserted and Asama = @duruminserted)
 SET @suredeleted = (SELECT DISTINCT  Sure FROM Sure WHERE ID = @iddeleted and Asama = @durumdeleted)
```

Second select first records

```
 SET @durumbilgisi = (SELECT TOP 1 DurumBilgisi FROM DurumBilgisi WHERE ID = @idinserted)
 SET @sureinserted = (SELECT TOP 1 Sure FROM Sure WHERE ID = @idinserted and Asama = @duruminserted)
 SET @suredeleted = (SELECT TOP 1 Sure FROM Sure WHERE ID = @iddeleted and Asama = @durumdeleted)
```

Comment: The first option will fail if the condition is matched for more than two rows

Comment: if the same record comes then it works and it's not defined records come same or not. May be comes the same records

Comment: Good content.Thank you